# Export The Roles

Tags: roles

I want to export the roles in salesforce to excel file or csv , is there anyway to do so, Any external tool is available for this exporting, could anyone fed some light on this.

Answer (score 4):

Roles are exposed in the API as [UserRole](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_role.htm). You could use the DataLoader to run a SOQL query against this sObject and extract all the records to a CSV.

---

The [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-SOQL-Queries.aspx) has an option to export SOQL query results as CSV.

It can export the SOQL query results as CSV. This will handle paging through all the query results for you.
[image: FuseIT SFDC Explorer Export SOQL results to CSV]

Disclosure: I work for the company that makes this product. It is free to download and use.

---

See also:

- [Exporting Data](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=exporting_data.htm) with the DataLoader.